# Mysql friends online display

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

OK,so I have headech from searching everywhere how to solve this problem..Im trying to show online users,but not all users,only who is in your friend list..

So I have table named users_online and when user logs-in in my website in that table is automaticly created 1 row with date,ip,name,user_id and friend_array (where all user's friends are kept)

So for example I log in in my website and row is created in users_online table. I want to see only my friends online and these friends are stored in friend_array column (1,5,16,5 (thats friends id number)).. How can I take data from friends_array colum and see which one of these id's are logged at the moment,which means which of these id's are existing in user_online table and display on my profile?

I hope is not confusing question...

Well thats my code..all stores in online.php file:

```
// Checking wheter the visitor is already marked as being online:
$inDB = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users_online WHERE user_id=".$userid);

if(!mysql_num_rows($inDB))
{
    // Selects some data required to insert into users_online table from users table
    $DB = mysql_query("SELECT img,fname,friend_array FROM users WHERE user_id=".$userid);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($DB))
    {
    $img = $row['img'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $farray = $row['friend_array'];
    }
    mysql_query("   INSERT INTO users_online (user_id,ip,img,fname,friend_array)
                    VALUES(".$userid.",'".$intIp."','".$img."','".$fname."','".$farray."')");
}
else
{
    // If the visitor is already online, just update the dt value of the row:
    mysql_query("UPDATE users_online SET dt=NOW() WHERE user_id=".$userid);
}


// Counting all the online visitors:
// Thats where i need to work out with friend array..
// I need to display all online friends only
list($totalOnline) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_online"));


// Outputting the number as plain text:
echo $totalOnline;
```

Comment: Consider taking the friends column into another table and store each friend a new row, not in array. Also don't insert new row per every login, but update the current timestamp value. You can also use `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE online = NOW()`

Comment: Well i thought about this as well. To create another table and use just id,user_id and friends_id..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $friends = array(1,5,16); // Array of friends
    $friendIDs = implode(',', $friends); // Turns array into string for SQL select statement

    // Gets only friends info from DB
    $sql = "
        SELECT date, ip, name, user_id
        FROM users_online
        WHERE user_id IN (".$friendIDs.")";
?>
```

Comment: Although without removing the entries from the user_online table when they go offline you will not get the results you expect after they leave...

Answer (score 2):

Sorted out guys! Thanks for your help!

```
//Selecting an array from db
$DB = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users_online WHERE user_id=".$userid);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($DB))
    {
    $friend_array = $row['friend_array'];
    $friends = array($friend_array); // Array of friends
    $friendIDs = implode(',', $friends);
    }
// Counting all the online friends:

list($totalOnline) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM users_online
        WHERE user_id IN (".$friendIDs.")"));


// Outputting the number as plain text:
echo $totalOnline;
```

Output was 1 user online as i was loged in with 2 browsers and in users_online table was created 2 rows with id 1 and 2..And id 1 had 3 friends in array (2,5,16), and user with id 2 had (1,3)..So in each of the browsers output was 1..Uray! I hope this question helps someone..Btw Im using update function on msql table and if user logs out,i just delete row in users_online table :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing the database schema. Here's an example:

USER table:

```
id | name | current_session_id
```

USER_FRIEND_USER table (contains friends that user has added):

```
user_id | friend_user_id
```

SESSION table:

```
id | user_id | created_at | expires_at
```

SQL Query to get list of friends for user with id '?':

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM USER u
  INNER JOIN USER_FRIEND_USER ufu ON (ufu.friend_user_id = u.id)
  INNER JOIN SESSION s ON (s.id = u.current_session_id)
  WHERE ufu.user_id = ? AND s.expires_at >= NOW();
```

Here's SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34f83/1/0